# Deserialize set of Confluent-encoded Avro in one file

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have a file which has binary avro appended next to each other. I would like to read each record one by one. At the same time, I would like to read first few bytes from each record which holds the schema id and then deserialize it. I am able to skip those bytes, using below code, and use the fixed schema. It works for me. But I would like to read each one individually. It that possible?

```
  val client = new SchemaRegistryClient("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL")
  val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(client.getSchema("TOPIC_NAME").get.toString)
  val reader = new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord](schema)
  val filename = "MY_BINARY_AVRO.avro"
  var fileContInBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename))
  val decoder = DecoderFactory.get.binaryDecoder(fileContInBytes, null)
  while (!decoder.isEnd) {
    decoder.skipFixed(5)
    val rec = reader.read(null, decoder)
  }
```

Python code which is able to deserialize binary avro, present next to each other, and seamlessly moving the bytes positions

```
from avro import schema, datafile, io
import io
import avro
import requests
import os

topic=r'TOPIC_NAME'
schemaurl=r'SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL'
OUTFILE_NAME = r'INPUT_BINARY_AVRO_FILE_LOCATION'
f=open(OUTFILE_NAME,'rb')
buf = io.BytesIO(f.read())
decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(buf)

while buf.tell()<os.path.getsize(OUTFILE_NAME):
  id=int.from_bytes((buf.read(4)), byteorder='big')
  SCHEMA = avro.schema.Parse(getSchema(schemaurl,id))
  rec_reader = avro.io.DatumReader(SCHEMA)
  out=rec_reader.read(decoder)
  print(out)
```

Comment: Avro files don't contain a schema ID, they typically contain the entire schema, then multiple records for that schema

Comment: Right. But I have a binary avro file where first few bytes represents schema id and rest of the bytes are data and so on.
Confluent deserializer handles such bytes array.
My Binary avro file is like this:
[SchemaId][data][scheid][data]...

Comment: I understand that might be what is in Kafka, but how did you get that file?? Because an Avro reader cannot deserialize it... You need to have block and record markers as per the Avro file spec

Comment: I read the data from kafka which has binary encoded avro. I use org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer to read as binary avro and store them in a file. I am able to deserialize it using the code above. However, I don't know if there's a way to read them one by one. And while writing the byte array, I just add them next to each other with no record separator.

Comment: That is a problem, then, because you need to know where one record ends and the next begins (such as storing how many bytes each record contains before you write it to the file). Even `kafka-avro-console-consumer` writing out to a file would be better (and it'll deserialize the message)

Comment: Look at this code below in Python. Seems to me that Python is able to move the pointer to the byte location using "read" method and after decoding the first record, the decoder is doing the same internally - moving the pointer to the next byte after the end of previous record. This works perfectly fine.
I guess my question is why Java api is different than python?
I edited the original post and added python code there.

Comment: I'm not sure how the internals of Java's `reader.read(null, decoder)` works, but in the Python code, looks like you are using the ID rather than a schema before the loop like the Java code. Is that what you are trying to ask? Rather than `decoder.skipFixed(5)`, you need to read those first few bytes

Comment: i am doing that in Java because, like in python, I cannot loop through. Python's Decoder api seems smart that it keeps track of the position until where it read. My goal is do something what that python code is doing. But the only way to read/ignore those first few bytes it s to do a skipFixed in Java.

Comment: Well, schema and reader can be moved into the loop. You're going to need to figure out what `buf.tell()` does in Python... Other than that, the only difference I see is getting the size of the Avro file

Comment: agreed, thanks for your feedback!